# How to calculate the LNB output frequency from a satellite transponder?

Tags: radio, antenna

There's a lot of sattelite tracking sites and other information sources that give tunning information as 'Ku band, elevation NN⁰, home transponder = 11015H'.

The question is, what 11015H means?
Considering Ku-low band to be 10.70-11.70 GHz, and the universal LNB I have with local oscillator in 9.75 GHz I'm thinking of:

```
11015H > 11.015GHz Horizontal polarity
11.015GHz - 9.75GHz = 1265KHz //the IF of that transponder in the LNB output
```

Well, tunning that frequency in fact gave me the proper transponder, but and for Ku-high band? Local oscillator is 10.6 GHz, and using the same math gives me 415KHz -that's out of the expected 950-2150 MHz L band range. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My calculations were right - it happens that this is the 'home transponder' - once it is tuned, the stream contains the frequency of the other TPs.
A given TP can be only in low or high band, not both (duh!).